# Maven source plugin - change JAR file name

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I am converting some projects to maven, from legacy ant builds
It so happened, that when we built with Ant, our sources were always called "fileName-**src**.jar".
Now, using maven, I need to keep the same naming.. but it seems that maven-source-plugin sets the name as "fileName-**sources**.jar"
How can I make "-source" not be appended? 
I am using the finalName in  but .. to no avail

```
 <configuration>
   <finalName>fileName-src</finalName>
   <fileNameMapping>no-version</fileNameMapping>
   <archive>
    <!-- ... manifest entries ...  -->
   </archive>
 </configuration>
```

As a result of this the jar will named "fileName-src**-source**.jar"

Comment: Do not try this. Better go with the conventions cause that's the most important paradigm which you should learn to follow. `<finalName>...</finalName>` is only available in some older plugin version which has been removed in newer versions...So if you start that way you will block yourself from updating...Apart from that other tools rely on this handling...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default classifier assigned by the [Maven Source Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/jar-mojo.html) is: `sources` so it will take the JAR's `finalName` and append `-sources`.

You can override this by setting the `classifier`.

For example:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <classifier>src</classifier>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks.  <classifier>src</classifier> works just as needed !!

Comment: What if I want to get rid of the whole classifier, including the hyphen?